# ffmpeg convert dvd vob to mp4 sometimes no audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, dvd

Using this cmd (from here : https://www.winxdvd.com/dvd-ripper/rip-dvd-with-ffmpeg.htm) to convert dvd vob files to mp4. (adjusting file names as needed)

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:VTS_01_1.VOB|VTS_01_2.VOB|VTS_01_3.VOB" -b:v 1500k -r 30 -vcodec h264 -strict -2 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -f mp4 convert.mp4
```

It has worked before on multiple dvds but now I've come to a dvd where the resulting mp4 has no audio. (I have confirmed that there is audio by playing the dvd in dvd player)

Is there something missing?

Cheers.

UPDATE:

@Rotem
The proposed cmd didn't work.

Key messages seem to be:

```
[mpeg2video @ 0000019386b69400] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
...
[fc#0 @ 00000193865ae280] Stream specifier ':a:0' in filtergraph description [0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0][3:v:0][3:a:0][4:v:0][4:a:0][5:v:0][5:a:0][6:v:0][6:a:0][7:v:0][7:a:0][8:v:0][8:a:0][9:v:0][9:a:0][10:v:0][10:a:0][11:v:0][11:a:0]concat=n=12:v=1:a=1[outv][outa] matches no streams.
```

Full cmd console output:

```
ffmpeg -i VIDEO_TS.VOB -i VTS_01_0.VOB -i VTS_01_1.VOB -i VTS_01_2.VOB -i VTS_01_3.VOB -i VTS_01_4.VOB -i VTS_01_5.VOB -i VTS_01_6.VOB -i VTS_01_7.VOB -i VTS_01_8.VOB -i VTS_02_0.VOB -i VTS_02_1.VOB -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0][3:v:0][3:a:0][4:v:0][4:a:0][5:v:0][5:a:0][6:v:0][6:a:0][7:v:0][7:a:0][8:v:0][8:a:0][9:v:0][9:a:0][10:v:0][10:a:0][11:v:0][11:a:0]concat=n=12:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -ar 44100 D:\dvd.mp4


ffmpeg -i VIDEO_TS.VOB -i VTS_01_0.VOB -i VTS_01_1.VOB -i VTS_01_2.VOB -i VTS_01_3.VOB -i VTS_01_4.VOB -i VTS_01_5.VOB -i VTS_01_6.VOB -i VTS_01_7.VOB -i VTS_01_8.VOB -i VTS_02_0.VOB -i VTS_02_1.VOB -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0][3:v:0][3:a:0][4:v:0][4:a:0][5:v:0][5:a:0][6:v:0][6:a:0][7:v:0][7:a:0][8:v:0][8:a:0][9:v:0][9:a:0][10:v:0][10:a:0][11:v:0][11:a:0]concat=n=12:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -ar 44100 D:\dvd.mp4
ffmpeg version 2023-12-28-git-c1340f3439-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --pkg-config=pkgconf --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      58. 36.100 / 58. 36.100
  libavcodec     60. 36.100 / 60. 36.100
  libavformat    60. 20.100 / 60. 20.100
  libavdevice    60.  4.100 / 60.  4.100
  libavfilter     9. 14.102 /  9. 14.102
  libswscale      7.  6.100 /  7.  6.100
  libswresample   4. 13.100 /  4. 13.100
  libpostproc    57.  4.100 / 57.  4.100
Input #0, mpeg, from 'VIDEO_TS.VOB':
  Duration: 00:00:00.02, start: 0.060000, bitrate: 4096 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
  Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m, progressive), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 9000 kb/s, 50 tbr, 90k tbn
      Side data:
        cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 9000000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
Input #1, mpeg, from 'VTS_01_0.VOB':
  Duration: 00:00:00.14, start: 0.060000, bitrate: 235544 kb/s
  Stream #1:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
  Stream #1:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m, progressive), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 9000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
      Side data:
        cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 7400000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #1:2[0x22]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
  Stream #1:3[0x21]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
Input #2, mpeg, from 'VTS_01_1.VOB':
  Duration: 00:28:12.60, start: 0.060000, bitrate: 5074 kb/s
  Stream #2:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
  Stream #2:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
      Side data:
        cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 7400000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #2:2[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.0(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
[mpeg2video @ 0000019386b69400] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 10 times
Input #3, mpeg, from 'VTS_01_2.VOB':
  Duration: 00:28:11.10, start: 1692.476000, bitrate: 5079 kb/s
  Stream #3:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
      Side data:
        cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 7400000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #3:1[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.0(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
  Stream #3:2[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
  Stream #3:3[0x22]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
  Stream #3:4[0x21]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
[mpeg2video @ 0000019386b66800] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 6 times
Input #4, mpeg, from 'VTS_01_3.VOB':
  Duration: 00:28:10.96, start: 3383.580000, bitrate: 5079 kb/s
  Stream #4:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
      Side data:
        cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 7400000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #4:1[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.0(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
  Stream #4:2[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
[mpeg2video @ 0000019386b73340] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 10 times
Input #5, mpeg, from 'VTS_01_4.VOB':
  Duration: 00:28:10.70, start: 5074.396000, bitrate: 5080 kb/s
  Stream #5:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
      Side data:
        cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 7400000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #5:1[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.0(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
  Stream #5:2[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
[mpeg2video @ 0000019386b73f40] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 8 times
Input #6, mpeg, from 'VTS_01_5.VOB':
  Duration: 00:28:12.53, start: 6765.052000, bitrate: 5075 kb/s
  Stream #6:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
      Side data:
        cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 7400000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #6:1[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.0(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
  Stream #6:2[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
  Stream #6:3[0x22]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
  Stream #6:4[0x21]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
[mpeg2video @ 0000019386b41500] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 10 times
Input #7, mpeg, from 'VTS_01_6.VOB':
  Duration: 00:28:12.16, start: 8457.404000, bitrate: 5076 kb/s
  Stream #7:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
      Side data:
        cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 7400000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #7:1[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.0(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
  Stream #7:2[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
[mpeg2video @ 0000019386b3f900] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
Input #8, mpeg, from 'VTS_01_7.VOB':
  Duration: 00:28:11.98, start: 10149.596000, bitrate: 5076 kb/s
  Stream #8:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
      Side data:
        cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 7400000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #8:1[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
  Stream #8:2[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.0(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
  Stream #8:3[0x22]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
  Stream #8:4[0x21]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
[mpeg2video @ 0000019386af1d80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 10 times
Input #9, mpeg, from 'VTS_01_8.VOB':
  Duration: 00:21:09.50, start: 11841.436000, bitrate: 5061 kb/s
  Stream #9:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
      Side data:
        cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 7400000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #9:1[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.0(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
  Stream #9:2[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
Input #10, mpeg, from 'VTS_02_0.VOB':
  Duration: 00:00:00.02, start: 0.060000, bitrate: 4096 kb/s
  Stream #10:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
  Stream #10:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m, progressive), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 9000 kb/s, 50 tbr, 90k tbn
      Side data:
        cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 9000000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
[mpeg @ 0000019386c9e500] stream 2 : no PTS found at end of file, duration not set
Input #11, mpeg, from 'VTS_02_1.VOB':
  Duration: 00:00:03.00, start: 0.060000, bitrate: 5559 kb/s
  Stream #11:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
  Stream #11:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 9000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
      Side data:
        cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 9000000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #11:2[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
[fc#0 @ 00000193865ae280] Stream specifier ':a:0' in filtergraph description [0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0][3:v:0][3:a:0][4:v:0][4:a:0][5:v:0][5:a:0][6:v:0][6:a:0][7:v:0][7:a:0][8:v:0][8:a:0][9:v:0][9:a:0][10:v:0][10:a:0][11:v:0][11:a:0]concat=n=12:v=1:a=1[outv][outa] matches no streams.
Error initializing complex filters: Invalid argument
PS V:\VIDEO_TS>
```

Comment: In theory, [concat protocol](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#protocol) should have worked with VOB files. You may look for the differences between the VOB files that work and the files that don't work using [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo). Tty using [Concat filter](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#filter): `ffmpeg -i VTS_01_1.VOB -i VTS_01_2.VOB -i VTS_01_3.VOB -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -ar 44100 convert.mp4`